# need to pass another value to change event

Tags: angular, forms, select

please give me advise, how can I solve this problem. I need to pass area.id to onChangeArea method to make request, but also I can not change value of options, because I need area.code in formControlName. How can I pass id to onChangeArea?[image]

Comment: having a dynamic name to `formControlName` seems a bit wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the `area.code` is unique then you can search the particular object from `areas` array in your controller.

```
getArea(code) {
    this.areas.forEach(function(area) {
        if(area.code === code) {
            console.log(area._id);
        }
    });
}
```

You can call this function onChange event.

Hope this will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the function by binding it with the click event of the dropdown.
You have the access to the whole object area at the options level. so just modify your code with the below lines of code.

```
<select id="area" class="form-control" #area formControlName="area">
  <option value="*" (click)="onAreadChange('*')">Bce</option>
  <option *ngFor="let area of areas" [value]="area.code" 
  (click)="onAreaChange(area._id)">
   {{area.code}}
  </option>
</select>
```